# Communicating with the UI Thread Android: User Inactivity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, android-handler

I have a Android application that verifies the user inactivity through a `Handler`. But I would like know if my `Handler` implementation is the best solution in my case.

The code:

```
public abstract class UserInteractionControlActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int SESSION_TIME_OUT = 300000;
    private static final int SESSION_DELAY_TIME = 60000;

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    private long mLastUserInterationTime;

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mHandler.postDelayed(new UserInteractionControl(), SESSION_TIME_OUT);
        Log.i("LOG_KEY", "HANDLER FIRST POST!");
    }

    public void onUserInteraction() {
        super.onUserInteraction();
        mLastUserInterationTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private final class UserInteractionControl implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long inactiveTime = currentTime - mLastUserInterationTime;
            if (inactiveTime > SESSION_TIME_OUT) {
                Log.i("LOG_KEY", "TIME OUT!");
            } else {
                mHandler.postDelayed(new UserInteractionControl(), SESSION_DELAY_TIME);
                Log.i("LOG_KEY", "HANDLER POST AGAIN!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My main questions are:

1) What is the difference between instantiate `Handler` using `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`  and `getWindow().getDecorView().getHandler()`?

2) The use of `System.currentTimeMillis()` in this context is secure?

Comment: The use of System.currentTimeMillis() in this context is secure? What do you mean?

Comment: Thanks for you comment @KristyWelsh! I asked this question because I do not know if the `System.currentTimeMillis()` will be amended in case the user change the time on Android OS. Because as I am trying to control user idle time, this would be a problem!

Comment: @Willis: "context" should not have been marked up as code - it was used in the literal sense.

Comment: 1) They are both functionally the same. 2) You can use `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the comments @corsair992! Already fixed the question!

Comment: Regarding the question of how to get a Handler object, this information may be of interest: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/114723/92925

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) As @corsair992 said, they should be equivalent, however I think having your own instance of `Handler` is preferable, as you explicitly control it. If you need to remove any pending `Runnable` instances later, you can just do a `removeCallbacksAndRunnables(null);` to remove any messages that your `Handler` has posted without affecting the decor view's `Handler`.

2) Don't use `System.currentTimeMillis()`. `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` is a much better indicator of elapsed time, as it won't be affected by the user changing the Date/Time (whereas `currentTimeMillis()` *does* change).

Comment: Thank you for answering @kcoppock! Both questions have been resolved! Thanks again!